# Powershell Increase mailbox size for 19 by 200MB Exchange 2007

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2007

I have CSV file with 19 users with different mailbox Quota, I want to be able to add 200mb more to their current mailbox size. if I tried set-mailbox it will change their current size and they all will have same mailbox quota which I dont want!! I only want to add 200MB to their current size.

```
$list = import-csv c:\list.csv 
foreach ($user in $list) {set-mailbox -identity $user.user -UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults $false -IssueWarningQuota 200MB -ProhibitSendQuota 250MB -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota 280MB}
```

To find mailbox quota script

```
$List = Import-Csv  C:\temp\Users_size.csv
foreach  ($user in $List){
  Get-Mailbox $user.user_id  |  fl name, *Quota    | Out-File -Append c:\size.csv 
  Get-MailboxStatistics $user.user_id | fl TotalItemSize  | Out-File -Append c:\size.csv}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com,  We'll help with your script if you get stuck but this isn't a script writing service.  You want to lookup mailbox info, return the mailbox size then add 200MB and finally set that mailbox quota.  Please search and post your script along with any errors.

Comment: Thanks User437867 for your reply:) not looking for someone to write my script but I thought users here are expert in powershell\excahnge and they share ideas 
so I was looking for ideas on how to accomplish my task:) My script will set all users to have the same mailbox size which I don’t want I am trying to find a way to add more space to their current size as they all have different mailbox quota due to their job needs. Again thank you for your prompt reply

Comment: So you are looking to change all quota values by 200mb that don't use the default quota for their database?

Comment: HI Matt, thank you for your reply:) I am  not looking to change the quota values, but looking to add 200 more to their current Quota... please note that they all have different quota and I am not looking to set all mailbox to the same size but add additional 200mb.  for instant Mailbox 1 is set to 1gb and mailbox 2 set to 750. How could I add additional 200mb so Mailbox will be 1.2gb and mailbox 2 will be 950mb

Comment: You need to provide a sample of the input csv-file. Does it have the current quota values or is it just a list of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `200MB` to the current quota-values inside the foreach-loop so the new value is unique for each user in the loop. I have no idea how your csv look like, so I created a sample-csv.

I don't have an Exchange-environment so this is all untested code

list.csv

```
User,IssueWarningQuota,ProhibitSendQuota,ProhibitSendReceiveQuota,SomeOtherColumns
User1,209715200,262144000,293601280,SomeOtherValue
User2,314572800,367001600,398458880,SomeOtherValue2
```

Sample:

```
$list = Import-Csv -Path c:\list.csv
foreach ($user in $list) {
    #Create variables with new quota-values for readability. Can be replaced with -IssueWarningQuoa ([int]$_.IssueWarningQuota + $AddQuota) -Prohi.... in the command itself.
    #Values from CSV are string by default, so we need to cast the value to int before adding (unless it will append to string).
    $IssueWarningQuota = [int]$_.IssueWarningQuota + 200MB
    $ProhibitSendQuota = [int]$_.ProhibitSendQuota + 200MB
    $ProhibitSendReceiveQuota = [int]$_.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota + 200MB

    Set-mailbox -identity $user.user -UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults $false -IssueWarningQuota $IssueWarningQuota -ProhibitSendQuota $ProhibitSendQuota -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota $ProhibitSendReceiveQuota
}
```

If your csv doesn't contain the current quota-values, you could use `Get-MailBox` to get them.

```
$list = Import-Csv -Path c:\list.csv
foreach ($user in $list) {
    $mb = Get-Mailbox $user.user

    $IssueWarningQuota = $mb.IssueWarningQuota + 200MB
    $ProhibitSendQuota = $mb.ProhibitSendQuota + 200MB
    $ProhibitSendReceiveQuota = $mb.ProhibitSendReceiveQuota + 200MB

    Set-mailbox -identity $user.user -UseDatabaseQuotaDefaults $false -IssueWarningQuota $IssueWarningQuota -ProhibitSendQuota $ProhibitSendQuota -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota $ProhibitSendReceiveQuota
}
```